# Scala generic implicit val

Tags: scala, generics, implicit

I have a lot of implicit val for enum to json transformations in my program like that:

```
implicit val format = new Format[AuthRoleIndividual] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(AuthRoleIndividual.withName(json.as[String]))
    def writes(myEnum: AuthRoleIndividual) = JsString(myEnum.toString)
  }
```

Note: `AuthRoleIndividual` extends `Enumeration`. My approach was to write something like that:

```
implicit val format[T <: Enumeration] = new Format[T] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(T.withName(json.as[String]))
    def writes(myEnum: T) = JsString(myEnum.toString)
  }
```

But that's not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way Play JSON already provides [`Writes`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Writes$@enumNameWrites[E%3C:Enumeration]:play.api.libs.json.Writes[E#Value]) and [`Reads`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads$@enumNameReads[E%3C:Enumeration](enum:E):play.api.libs.json.Reads[E#Value]) for enumerations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You are misunderstanding the `Enumeration` value's type, For `Enumeration` value, the **value**'s type is `Value` type not `Enumeration` , so you should bind the `implicit` for `Value` type. For Example:

```
  object State extends Enumeration {
    val A = Value("A")
    val B = Value("B")
  }

  implicit def foo(v: State.Value): String = v.toString + "-Bar"

  val t: String = State.A
```

Secondly, As the above code, Since the `Value` type is bind to the `object`(`State.value`), you can't create **generic implicits** for all `Enumeration`.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarification!